# Better Way to Find Item in Custom Collection Class Then For Loop for Index

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I'm learning about storing multiple values for a Key in VBA. My research has lead to me to utilize a custom Collection Class.

I got it to work in theory and then in practice I wanted to look up values based on the key but was only able to do it via "index number". I then generated a `Property` to return that index number, but that means if I have to loop through Keys each each will loop through the entire collection to find the index number before moving forward. This seems like too much computation and I'm wondering if there is a way to use a dicitonary key/value setup to store the Keys Index and have this all setup inside the Collection Class so I can directly call a keys value via it's index from the dictionary.

Here is my code so far:

**Module:**

```
'https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s239/collections.htm
Sub CreatePeople()

 Dim p1 As New clsPersons, p2 As New clsPersons, p3 As New clsPersons

 With p1
  .FirstName = "Rita"
  .LastName = "Smith"
 End With

 With p2
  .FirstName = "Sue"
  .LastName = "Jones"
 End With
 
  With p3
  .FirstName = "Bob"
  .LastName = "Brown"
 End With
 
 Debug.Print p1.FirstName, p1.LastName, p1.FullName
 Debug.Print p1.FullName, p2.FullName, p3.FullName

End Sub
Sub CreatePersonsCollectionSafer()
 Dim Persons As New clsPersons

 Persons.Add "Rita", "Smith"
 Persons.Add "Sue", "Jones"
 Persons.Add "Bob", "Brown"
  
 Dim Person As clsPersons
 Dim PersonNumber As Integer
 Debug.Print Persons.Count
 For PersonNumber = 1 To Persons.Count
  Debug.Print Persons.Item(PersonNumber).FullName
 Next PersonNumber
 
 Dim LastName As String
 LastName = "Brown"
 Debug.Print "Last Name = " & LastName & " & First Name = " & Persons.ItemByLastName(LastName).FirstName
 
End Sub
```

---

**Class (clsPersons):**

```
Option Explicit
Private Persons As New Collection
Private Person As clsPersons
Public FirstName As String
Public LastName As String
''Subs
Sub Add(FirstName As String, LastName As String)
 Dim p As New clsPersons
 
 p.FirstName = FirstName
 p.LastName = LastName

 Persons.Add p

End Sub

Sub Remove(NameOrNumber As Variant)
 Persons.Remove NameOrNumber
End Sub
''EndSubs

''Properties

Property Get Count() As Long
 Count = Persons.Count
End Property

Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As clsPersons
 Set Item = Persons(Index)
End Property

Property Get FullName() As String
 FullName = FirstName & " " & LastName
End Property

Property Get Items() As Collection
 Set Items = Persons
End Property

Property Get ItemByLastName(LastName As String) As clsPersons
 Dim PersonsIndex As Integer
 For PersonsIndex = 1 To Persons.Count
  Debug.Print Persons.Item(PersonsIndex).LastName
  If Persons.Item(PersonsIndex).LastName = LastName Then
   Set ItemByLastName = Persons(PersonsIndex)
   Exit For
  End If
 Next PersonsIndex
End Property

''EndProperties
```

Comment: A Scripting.DIctionary looks to be a better object for your use case compared to Collection.  As an Aid, Class Persons should be the 'Collection' object which holds a scripting.Dictionary of Class Person.  You will also need to think about how you will handle people with the same surname, and/or first name.

Comment: Hint.  A Scripting .Dictions(COllection or ArrayList) can be nested as VBA doesn't preculde A a Scripting.Dictionary where the values are themselves scripting.dictionaries.  So my hint is that you collection class may end up being based on a Scripting.Dictionary that is nested three levels deep.

Comment: This is just example data that is not my data... more like ordernumber, orderitem, orderamount,orderdate etc

Comment: @freeflow that sounds way overly complicated? This works well so far, and I did resolve this issue, but now I'm struggling to make the collection persistent/public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the keys provided by the collection. You don't need an extra collection/dictionary.

```
Sub Add(FirstName As String, LastName As String)
 Dim p As New clsPersons
 
 p.FirstName = FirstName
 p.LastName = LastName

 Persons.Add p, LastName 
End Sub
Property Get ItemByLastName(LastName As String) As clsPersons
   Set ItemByLastName = Persons(LastName)
End Property
```

However, you should not be working with a single class here. You are basically holding a new collection of persons inside each person. You should have a Person and a Persons class to make code easier to read and maintain.

You should also hide your members and expose getters to achieve encapsulation. In your code you can easily change the name of a person and thus the keys will be useless.

Here is a different approach:

`Person` class:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_firstName As String
Private m_lastName As String
Private m_initialized As Boolean

Public Function Init(ByVal firstName_ As String, ByVal lastName_ As String) As Boolean
    If m_initialized Then
        Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me) & ".Init", "Already initialized"
    End If
    If firstName_ = vbNullString Or lastName_ = vbNullString Then Exit Function 'Returns False
    
    m_firstName = firstName_
    m_lastName = lastName_
    m_initialized = True
    
    Init = True
End Function

Property Get FirstName() As String
    FirstName = m_firstName
End Property

Property Get LastName() As String
    LastName = m_lastName
End Property

Property Get FullName() As String
    FullName = m_firstName & " " & m_lastName
End Property

Public Function Self() As Person
    Set Self = Me
End Function
```

`Persons` class:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_persons As New Collection

Public Function Add(ByVal p As Person) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next 'Name can already exist
    m_persons.Add p, p.LastName 'Or maybe full name would be better as multiple persons can share the same last name
    Add = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function AddFromValues(ByVal firstName_ As String, ByVal lastName_ As String) As Boolean
    With New Person
        If Not .Init(firstName_, lastName_) Then Exit Function
        AddFromValues = Me.Add(.Self)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub Remove(ByVal indexOrLastName As Variant)
    m_persons.Remove indexOrLastName
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_persons.Count
End Property

Property Get Item(ByVal indexOrLastName As Variant) As Person
    Set Item = m_persons(indexOrLastName)
End Property

Property Get Items() As Collection
    Set Items = m_persons
End Property

Public Function Exists(ByVal lastName_ As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    m_persons.Item lastName_
    Exists = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

and then the testing code in a standard .bas module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreatePeople()
    Dim p1 As New Person
    Dim p2 As New Person
    Dim p3 As New Person
    
    p1.Init "Rita", "Smith"
    p2.Init "Sue", "Jones"
    p3.Init "Bob", "Brown"
     
    Debug.Print p1.FirstName, p1.LastName, p1.FullName
    Debug.Print p1.FullName, p2.FullName, p3.FullName
End Sub

Public Sub CreatePersonsCollectionSafer()
    Dim myPersons As New Persons

    myPersons.AddFromValues "Rita", "Smith"
    myPersons.AddFromValues "Sue", "Jones"
    myPersons.AddFromValues "Bob", "Brown"

    Dim tempPerson As Person

    For Each tempPerson In myPersons.Items
        Debug.Print tempPerson.FullName
    Next tempPerson

    Dim lastNameToSearch As String
    
    lastNameToSearch = "Brown"
    Debug.Print "Last Name = " & lastNameToSearch & " & First Name = " _
        & myPersons.Item(lastNameToSearch).FirstName
End Sub
```

Comment: I knew that there was already a key in the collection, but I was having trouble searching by it. This does seem more logical. I like that I can use `Dic.Exists` but in your example, I could make the same `Get Exists` property im sure. To be clear, in your example, only the last name is the key correct? This just sample data, so how do I know that "lastname" is the key? Or can I search by FirstName too?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I've edited the answer and added the ```Exists``` method. In my example the last name is the key, yes. You could create your initial method ```ItemByLastName``` that receives a ```ByVal lastName_ As String``` parameter and the code inside would be like ```Set ItemByLastName = m_persons(lastName_)```. If you want to search by first name then ask yourself if the first name will be unique. If no, it cannot be a key. If yes, you need a second collection to hold a firstName-person mapping but then you need to synchronize the collections and it gets difficult

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Moreover, once you have 2 collections you cannot expose them anymore (e.g. your ```Items``` method) because you could delete items from a collection once you retrieve it and that would ruin the synchronization.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Finally, if you decide that you are going to create the ```ItemByLastName``` method and you later change the keys to full name then you will need to rename the method to ```ItemByFullName```. Whatever you decide, just make sure you keep things synchronized.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Forgot to answer one of your questions. In the ```Get Item``` property the name of the parameter is ```indexOrLastName``` so that should indicate that the key is last name. Hope I've covered all your questions.

Comment: But when I use real data, how do I know which item is the `key`? This data is just example data again, I will not be using names at all. My code is working as of now, but I'll re-work it with this method soon enough and accept.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers You will have to choose a field that is unique (e.g. an ID) and you use that as the key. It really depends on your data. Then you build your custom collection around that unique field which will act as key. It could be a composite key (e.g. full name in your question) composed of more than one field.

Comment: Right, but what tells me that `LastName` is the key? other then the fact you search by it in  get property? Can I just change that line to say `FirstName` or is the LastName definined somewhere in genearting the collection that it is the key. Does this line define the key `Persons.Add p, LastName `?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Yes, that line defines the key. The ```Add``` method of the ```Collection``` has 4 parameters. First is the item and second is the key. In my example the ```m_persons.Add p, p.LastName``` line does exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue via the following:

```
Private PersonsIndexDic As Object

Sub Add(FirstName As String, LastName As String)
 Dim p As New clsPersons
 
 p.FirstName = FirstName
 p.LastName = LastName

 Persons.Add p
 
 PersonsIndexDic.Add Key:=LastName, Item:=PersonsIndexDic.Count + 1
End Sub

Property Get ItemByLastName(LastName As String) As clsPersons
   Set ItemByLastName = Persons(PersonsIndexDic(LastName))
End Property
```

Test:

```
 Dim LastName As String
 LastName = "Brown"
 Debug.Print "Last Name = " & LastName & " & First Name = " & Persons.ItemByLastName(LastName).FirstName
```